Why is the Turing Jump Baire Class 1?
Recall that a function $f: 2^\omega \to 2^\omega$ is Baire Class $1$ if it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions. And a function is Baire Class 1 iff it is $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_2$-measurable that is $\forall U \text{ open } (f^{-1}[U] \text{ is } \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_2)$ (i.e. $f^{-1}[U]$ is a countable union of closed).
I found written multiple times (for example here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/301627/522356) that the Turing Jump function is Baire Class 1. It is defined as:
\begin{align*}
TJ : 2^\omega &\to 2^\omega\\
x &\mapsto x' = \{ e \in \omega \mid \varphi^x_e(e)\downarrow\}
\end{align*}
(Where $(\varphi^x_e)_{e \in \omega}$ is an enumeration of the computable functions with oracle $x$ and the down arrow means that the functions halts on the given input).
The problem is that I don't know how to prove it and no one explains it. I tried to show that $TJ$ is $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_2$-measurable but I'm not sure if sets of the form $I_n = \{x \in 2^\omega \mid \varphi^x_n(n) \downarrow \}$ are open/clopen or not.

If $\varphi_n^x(n)\downarrow$, then there is some finite initial segment $\sigma$ of $x$ (the use of the computation) such that for all $y$ extending $\sigma$ we have $\varphi^y_n(n)\downarrow$ as well; this is just because a halting computation can only query finitely many bits of the oracle. Consequently, each set of the form $\{x: \varphi^x_n(n)\downarrow\}$ is open. (Of course, such sets are not generally clopen - think about an oracle machine which scans the oracle looking for a nonzero bit ...)

So if I want to write each $I_n$ as explicit union of cilinders of the Cantor space (said $N_s$ $\forall s \in 2^{<\omega}$), I can chose for each $x \in 2^\omega$ a $\sigma_x$ in the corresponding initial segments that satisy the finite use property and then I have $I_n = \bigcup_{{\sigma_x \mid x \in 2^\omega}} N_{\sigma_x}$, right? Is there a more elegant way to write it?

@NON There's a common convention in computability theory to make sense of "$\varphi_m^\sigma(n)$" with $\sigma$ a finite string; we just have the machine go into an endless loop (= not halt) if it tries to query a bit beyond the length of $\sigma$. Using this notation we can write $$I_n=\bigcup_{\varphi_n^\sigma(n)\downarrow}N_\sigma,$$ which is a bit cleaner although not substantively different. (Separately, I'd use "witness" instead of "satisfy;" it's not that the segments in question satisfy the finite use property, it's that they're the objects whose existence that property demands.)
